# Cyclic vectors for C* algebras

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras

Let A be a C* algebra of operators on a Hilbert space H. Can it happen that for some x in H the set Ax is dense in H but it is not the whole H?

Comment: Did you check the commutative case?

Comment: You might be interested in the article "Somewhere dense orbits are everywhere dense" by Bourdon and Feldman, 
http://home.wlu.edu/~feldmann/Papers/SomewhereDense.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes, as per Nik Weaver's hint: E.g. $C[0,1]$ acting by multiplication on $L_2[0,1]$.

Comment: Some wisdom I learned from Chuck Akemann: first check the commutative case, then check the $2\times 2$ matrices. If both of those cases work, there's a good chance it's true in general.